# Testing that a multivariate mean approximately equals a vector of constants

Tags: hypothesis-testing, multivariate-analysis, equivalence, hotelling-t2

Suppose we have a $p$-variate random vector that has a multivariate Normal distribution, $\boldsymbol{X}\sim MVN(\boldsymbol{\mu},\Sigma)$. My hypothesis is that the mean vector contains only zeros, $\boldsymbol{\mu}=\boldsymbol{0}$. I think I can test that using Hotelling's $T^2$.

Now, I do not really believe my model is exactly correct, but I need it to be a good enough approximation. And I have a clear measure of what is good enough. I consider three cases of such a measure:

1. $\boldsymbol{\mu}^\top\boldsymbol{\mu}<c$,
2. $\sum_{j=1}^p|\mu_j|<c$,
3. $\max_{j\in 1,\dots,p}|\mu_j|<c$.

How would I test 1., 2. or 3.?

Comment: Cool question! You would use a different $c$ in $(1)$ than $(2)$, right? // Particularly in $(1)$, you might consider something like (squared) Mahalanobis distance, rather than the usual notion of distance. Something similar could apply to $(2)$, but I do not know what. // I would be curious to know how robust proposed tests are to deviations for the multivariate normal assumption.

Comment: @Dave, thanks! Yes, $c$ would be different in (1) vs. (2). I would only do one of the options, (1) or (2), not both, so I would not have to compare $c$ from one to $c$ from the other. Regarding distance, I am actually interested in (2), but I doubt it can be easily done, so I consider (1) as a simplification. I suppose it does not get simpler than that. Regarding the assumption of multivariate normality, that is a valid concern. But again, I am starting from the simplest possible case to probe what is possible. My actual problem is a little more complex than the one I have posted.

Comment: I wonder if some kind of bootstrap confidence ellipsoid would be useful here. Bootstrap your data, calculate either distance metric, and calculate a confidence ellipsoid. If that ellipsoid is contained within an acceptable distance (defined by $c$), then you're within the tolerance. (This makes sense in the univariate case, right?)

Comment: @Dave, could you elaborate just a bit? I do not quite follow.

Comment: Maybe it's just a usual bootstrap. Resample your data, calculate $(1)$ or $(2)$, and repeat this over and over. Then you can use a bootstrap confidence interval of the many calculated metrics. If that confidence interval does not contain $c$, then you have statistical evidence that your vector is no more than $c$ away from the zero-vector.

Comment: @Dave, I have little experience with bootstrap (I tend read about it every now and then but do not really use it, so I always forget what I have read), so I cannot judge whether this is a valid approach or not. It sounds fine, though. Perhaps you can post this as an answer, and let us see what others think about it. Also, I have added a third case that I think can make sense for my problem. But if you can address one or two, it is still good.

Comment: Nice question. So, apart from the bootstrap idea, I started thinking about the univariate case assuming known $\sigma^2,$ which means the null region is $|\mu|<c.$ In this specific scenario, let's start with the LRT statistic. With LRT, the $\mu=0$ null and $|\mu|<c$ possibly give a different test statistic. 
Apart from LRT, as far as I remember, the UMPU test is there, which you can use. 

In the multivariate scenario, I think LRT can be extended for case 1 for a normal model, but I am unsure about cases 2 and 3.

Comment: Do you only have a single measurement $X$ and is $\Sigma$ known. Or do you have several measurements based on which you make an estimate of $\Sigma$?

Comment: @SextusEmpiricus, my sample size is not 1, it is definitely larger than 1. $\Sigma$ is not known, it has to be estimated.

Answer (score 0):

My first thought is to use a bootstrap approach.

1. Take a bootstrap sample of your data.
2. Calculate and store quantity $(1)$, $(2)$, or $(3)$ of your bootstrap sample
3. Repeat, repeat, repeat...

Now you have a bunch of numbers. Use them to compute a confidence interval using one of the usual bootstrap methods (e.g., BCa).

If that entire confidence interval is lower than $c$, then you have statistical evidence that the population-level value of $(1)$, $(2)$, or $(3)$ is less than $c$. If you need a p-value, you might figure out the confidence level at which the upper limit of the confidence interval *just* touches $c$.

**AS AN ASIDE**, it might make more sense to take the square root of $(1)$. Then all three of your measures are $L_p$ norms and reasonably called distances between your mean vector and the zero vector. Then again, if you have reason to care about $(1)$ as it is written, go for it!

Comment: I look forward to other ideas, particularly if there are analytical solutions to this and how robust this bootstrap approach is to deviations from multivariate normality.