# Intuition behind rank of covariance matrix and testing hypotheses

Tags: multivariate-analysis, covariance-matrix, intuition, linear-algebra, degrees-of-freedom

I am trying to acquire some intuition about testing multivariate hypotheses where the test statistic involves inverse covariance matrix. As an example, suppose we have a $p$-variate random vector that has a multivariate normal distribution, $\boldsymbol{X}\sim MVN(\boldsymbol{\mu},\Sigma)$, and we have a sample of size $n$. The hypothesis is that the mean vector contains only zeros, $H_0\colon \boldsymbol{\mu}=\boldsymbol{0}$. I think we can test that using Hotelling's $T^2$.* We need $n>p$ to ensure the sample covariance matrix $\hat\Sigma$ in the test statistic is invertible; there are some great posts explaining that (e.g. [1](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/178587), [2](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/70899), [3](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/60622)**).

While I sort of get how the rank of $\hat\Sigma$ is determined by the sample size, I still wonder how we can estimate its $\frac{p(p+1)}{2}$ unique elements from just $n$ data points if $n<\frac{p(p+1)}{2}$ in such a way that $\hat\Sigma$ is full rank. Does that mean these elements are in some sense "independent" (there must be a better term for what I mean here) of each other so that estimating one of them does not consume degrees of freedom w.r.t. estimating another one? If we tried to test a joint hypothesis about all the $n<\frac{p(p+1)}{2}$ unique elements in $\Sigma$, would we not run into something akin to noninvertible sample covariance matrix corresponding to these elements (let us call that matrix $\hat\Omega$)? And if we would, why is that not a problem when testing hypotheses in which we use $\hat\Sigma$?

<sub>*[Here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/606156) is a related question.</sub>
<sub>**I also think there was another great answer by @ttnphns in a thread that was closed as a duplicate, but [I do not know how find it](https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6465).</sub>

Comment: Sorry for the quality of the formulation. I am struggling to understand what I do not understand and what I need to understand :)

Comment: [mini partial answer:] If we were just comparing the "number of numbers", i.e. regarding that $n<\frac{p(p+1)}{2}$, note that each of our $n$ vectors has $p$ many numbers in it. If we forget for a moment that the matrix is symmetric, then we have $np < p^2$, which gives us $n=p$ as desired.